# How to make required atleast one checkbox when one of the main check box is checked

Tags: javascript, php, web, checkbox

I want to require at least one checkbox from all when one of the upper checkboxes is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M3GW.png)clicked. the snap is attached herewith.

here is the javascript code

```
function toggleOtherTextboxVisiblewh()
{
    var check = document.getElementById('wh');
    var chk2=document.getElementsByName('s1[]');
   var chk3=document.getElementsByName('q1[]');
    if (check.checked) {
        document.getElementById('sizewh').style.display = 'block';
        
    }
    else {
           document.getElementById('sizewh').style.display = 'none';
      
           for (i=0;i<chk2.length;i++)
                chk2[i].checked=false;
                
           for (b=0;b<chk3.length;b++)
                chk3[b].value = "";
    }            
            


}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to make at least one checkbox which is size required when user select any color checkbox

Comment: also my javascript code display those size checkboxes when the color is selected and when it deselect color the box will disappear even all checkboxes are also unchecked

Comment: What I meant was, show us the code you've tried so far, and describe how it doesn't do what you need it to.